# Running integration tests automatically on github

Tags: azure, testing, github, integration-testing

Is there any existing tooling/platform I can use to do the following?

1. On any github PR or commit, have a custom "check", e.g the same as how travis-ci works.
2. Have this task talk to a remote machine on azure.
3. Execute a script on this machine and collect logs/exit code
4. Fail the check if the code is none zero or timeout is reached.
5. Handle queuing if two PR's come in, clean up on abort etc.
6. Have some sort of "status" badge like travis-ci to see the current test state/pass rate.

So far only travis-ci itself seems to work something like this, but whatever I execute will run in their cloud so I don't "own" the machine. Additionally my integration tests require copyrighted data which needs to be kept safe on my own cloud machine, and could take multiple hours to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/ describes how to do this. Your machine will need to be accessible to github to do this.